# DisplayPort Daisy Chaining Fails with BenQ PD2710QC + LG 32MA68HY-P

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, displayport, daisychaining

I have a 5th gen X1 Carbon running fully-patched Windows 10. Attempting to use DisplayPort daisychain with:

- BenQ PD2710QC (primary monitor, native resolution 2560x1440, connects to laptop via USB-C)
- LG 32MA68HY-P (secondary monitor, native resolution 1920x1080, connected to BenQ monitor via brand new DisplayPort cable)

The BenQ has options for DisplayPort 1.1/1.2, and MST off/on.

With DisplayPort 1.2 and MST on, the operating system recognizes both monitors, but the LG monitor always gives a "no signal" error.

With DisplayPort 1.2 and MST off, the operating system also recognizes both monitors, but the LG monitor always gives a "signal out of range" error.

In either setting, the native 1920x1080 resolution for the LG monitor doesn't appear in Windows settings, only 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x720 and 1280x800. If I cycle through those settings, it makes no differnece.

With DisplayPort 1.1 (MST off or on), I am able to get an image on both monitors, but they both revert to the lower resolution of the LG monitor, i.e. 1920x1080. Windows does not then allow me to use the 2560x1440 resolution of the BenQ Monitor.

My understanding was that it shouldn't matter whether the secondary LG monitor supports DisplayPort 1.1 or 1.2 since it is the last monitor in the (1-monitor) chain. It's unclear from the LG monitor documentation which DP version it supports.

Any suggestions on how to figure out if what I'm trying to do is even possible? Documentation for DisplayPort daisy chaining on both monitors is pretty sparse.